# Passing RadioButton Value to Controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I am trying to pass a radiobutton value to a controller. However I cannot seem to figure out how to get the value I pass through. I am not sure what to do with the controller.

Model that I use to keep the value

```
public class PendingTasksModel
{
    public string environmentName { get; set; }
}
```

View

```
<div class="col-md-3">
    <div class="btn-group-vertical pull-right" data-toggle="buttons">
         <label class="btn btn-primary" style="@displayOak">
             @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.environmentName, "OAK")
             OAK
         </label>
         <label class="btn btn-primary" style="@displayQa">
             @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.environmentName, "QA")
             QA
         </label>
         <label class="btn btn-primary" style="@displayProd">
             @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.environmentName, "PROD")
             PROD
         </label>
     </div>
 </div>
```

Controller

```
public ActionResult InitializeService(PendingTaskModel model)
    {
        _binding = new BasicHttpBinding();
        if (model.environmentName == "OAK")
        {
            _endpointAddress = new EndpointAddress(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["OAK"]);
        }
        else if (model.environmentName == "PROD")
        {
            _binding.Security.Mode = BasicHttpSecurityMode.Transport;
            _endpointAddress = new EndpointAddress(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["PROD"]);
        }
        else
        {
            _binding.Security.Mode = BasicHttpSecurityMode.Transport;
            _endpointAddress = new EndpointAddress(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["QA"]);
        }
        _channel = new ChannelFactory<IEisIntegrationService>(_binding, _endpointAddress);

        try
        {
            _target = _channel.CreateChannel();


        }
        catch
        {
            if (_target != null)
            {
                ((ICommunicationObject)_target).Abort();
            }
        }
        return View();
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

In order for the MVC infrastructure to automatically wire up form fields to your controllers, you need to ensure that your parameter names and types match up.  Try changing your `string option` parameter to `PendingTasksModel model` and then check `model.environmentName` in your if statements.  Alternately, change `string option` to `string environmentName`

Comment: Ok, I made the changes see above. However, for some reason it seems like the InitializeService Method never gets reached. Do I have to use a @Html.Action in my View or something?

Comment: Do you have a BeginForm and a submit button?